# Detect page redirection and execute code

Tags: 7, uri, redirection

I have two modules which I am trying to make work in synch.

The first module creates a dynamic page and redirects users if certain conditions are met. The redirect URL takes to following form: `testsite/event/registration/success/277/466`.

When the redirect happens, I want my second module to detect the redirection and pickup from when the first module left off. I am trying to make it check and determine if the user is on: `testsite/event/registration/success/*/*`

Is this possible and can anyone give me some direction, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use [hook_drupal_goto_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_drupal_goto_alter/7) to achieve this. It'll get called during the processing of the redirection.